# NIS client setup

Tags: 14.04, package-management, nis

I just upgraded to 14.04 from 13.10. After the upgrade NIS stopped working. I went in, checked the settings (`hosts, yp.conf, nsswitch`) - everything seems to be configured correctly. But... I can't find `/etc/init.d/nis` anymore. When I try to install nis, I see this:

```
root@crab:~# apt-get install nis
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nis is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  hostname:i386 hostname

E: Package 'nis' has no installation candidate
```

Here's the output of `apt-cache policy`:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-app-review-     board,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Application Review Board PPA,c=main
     origin extras.ubuntu.com
 500 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-app-review- board,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Application Review Board PPA,c=main
     origin extras.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Any advice? Thank you.